# Why this PDO parametrized query behave "strangely"?

Tags: pdo

Here i have edited my original question. 
I have alswo answered it, in my next message.

I'm trying to get results from MySQL with parametrized php PDO query, but thing behaves strangley. I dont know if it is a bug, or I am doing something wrong or not seeing something obvious.

Lets suppose there are these two tables in database

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
) 

CREATE TABLE `users_contacts` (
`contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
`user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Fill them with minimal data :

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`) VALUES (125);

INSERT INTO `users_contacts` (`contact_id`, `user_id`, `type`, `value`) 
    VALUES(11432, 125, 'email', 'losleyTyped@offten.stinks'),
          (11433, 125, 'phone', '1234567'),
          (564, 125, 'unit', '910');
```

And then you try to fetch data like this

```
$db_name = "";
$db_user = "";
$db_pass = "";
$db_pdo  = new pdo("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db_name","$db_user","$db_pass");


$user          = 125;
$user_unit_btm = 900;
$user_unit_top = $user_unit_btm + 100;

$upload_user = $db_pdo -> prepare("SELECT K.value AS unit
                                    FROM users AS O, 
                                         users_contacts AS K 
                                    WHERE   O.user_id = :user_id AND 
                                            K.user_id = O.user_id AND 
                                            K.type = 'unit' AND 
                                            K.value >= :unit_btm AND  
                                            K.value < :unit_top
                                 ");


$upload_user -> execute( [":user_id"   => $user,
                          ":unit_btm"  => $user_unit_btm,
                          ":unit_top"  => $user_unit_top
                         ]
                       );


$upload_user = $upload_user -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($upload_user);
```

**var_dump will return false, but there is no error(err is 0000)**

I have reduced the problem, and find that only one parameter ":organization" is problematic and cause for bizare behevior.

But if you replace " K.value < :unit_top " 
with variable $user_unit_top
    " K.value < $user_unit_top "
Then, query returns result!

Same thing if i replace " K.value < :unit_top " with literal 1000,
    " K.value < 100"
Then query returns result!

Why is this happening?

Comment: You are welcome: [How To Debug Any Strange Behavior With Your PDO Code, Or Come Up With MCVE For Stack Overflow](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve)

Comment: Under your `execute()` call, put `print_r($upload_user->errorInfo());` [\[sic\]](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php), Please update your question with the output.

Comment: "Your Common Sense" i will try to form the question in that manner

Comment: @fyrye sorry i did not mentioned i already tried that and there is no error, result is   Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )  I also tried $upload_user->debugDumpParams() and everything seams to be in place

Comment: Interesting, typically if `execute` is returning `false`, it indicates an error occurred. Enable `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` as demonstrated in the article that Your Common Sense posted and see if your query throws an exception.

Comment: @fyrye thanx, i will do that but it will take some time, problem is that I cannot do it on current server i do not have permissions, I have to setup new enviroment. I will POST my findings

Comment: i find out what was the problem, i will post it as soon as i comprehend the MCVE whay of asking/answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment to your answer.

The PHP documentation on `PDOStatement::execute` states.

> An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as `PDO::PARAM_STR`.
>   Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Additionally `PDOStatement::fetch()` returns `false` when there are no more results or upon failure.

> The return value of this function on success depends on the fetch type. In all cases, `FALSE` is returned on failure.

Example https://3v4l.org/NVECJ

```php
$pdo = new \PDO('sqlite::memory:', null, null, [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
]);
$pdo->query('CREATE TABLE foo(id INTEGER)');

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM foo');
$stmt->execute();
var_dump($stmt->fetch());
//bool(false)
```

If you need to explicitly define a data type, other than `PDO::PARAM_STR` for the parameter being sent to MySQL, you would use [`PDOStatement::bindParam`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [`PDOStatement::bindValue`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

Example:

```php
$upload_user = $db_pdo->prepare('SELECT 
        K.value AS unit
    FROM users AS O, 
        users_contacts AS K 
    WHERE O.user_id = :user_id 
    AND K.user_id = O.user_id
    AND K.type = \'unit\'
    AND K.value >= :unit_btm
    AND K.value < :unit_top');
$upload_user->bindValue(':user_id', $user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$upload_user->bindValue(':unit_btm', $user_unit_btm, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$upload_user->bindValue(':unit_top', $user_unit_top, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$upload_user->execute();
```

An alternative would be to force data type casting on the parameter in the query.

```php
$upload_user = $db_pdo->prepare('SELECT 
        K.value AS unit
    FROM users AS O, 
        users_contacts AS K 
    WHERE O.user_id = :user_id
    AND K.user_id = O.user_id
    AND K.type = \'unit\' 
    AND K.value >= (:unit_btm - 0)
    AND K.value < (:unit_top - 0)'); //CAST(:unit_top AS SIGNED)
$upload_user->execute([
    ':user_id' => $user,
    ':unit_btm' => $user_unit_btm,
    ':unit_top' => $user_unit_top
]);
```

---

Another contributing factor to your issue, is that MySQL will perform an automatic conversion to the column's data type for the comparison. Where other RDMBS, like PostgreSQL and SQLite3 do not perform the same conversions.

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type
>   conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions
>   occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts strings to
>   numbers as necessary, and vice versa.
>   Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html

Since your initial column data type was `VARCHAR`, this resulted in the following from your testing.
[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PRhxf3gusMq75sZs3biKK/1)

Initial query as `PDOStatement::execute([1000])`.

```sql
SELECT IF('910' > '1000', 'fail', 'pass') AS if_str_to_str;

| if_str_to_str |
| ------------- |
| fail          |
```

Manually supplying integer to the Query

```sql
SELECT IF('910' > 1000, 'fail', 'pass') AS if_str_to_int;

| if_str_to_int |
| ------------- |
| pass          |
```

After changing the database column data type and using `PDOStatement::execute([1000])`

```sql
SELECT IF(910 > '1000', 'fail', 'pass') AS if_int_to_str;

| if_int_to_str |
| ------------- |
| pass          |
```

Using `PDOStatement::bindValue(':param', '1000', PDO::PARAM_INT)` or `('1000' - 0)`

```sql
SELECT IF('910' > CAST('1000' AS SIGNED), 'fail', 'pass') AS if_str_to_typecast_int;

| if_str_to_typecast_int |
| ---------------------- |
| pass                   |
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an answer if somebody else find him self with similar problem

> Why is this happening?

I think it is because Php or MySQL automatic type recognition/casting

Take a look of the table `users_contacts` the column named 'value' is of type `VARCHAR` (because the table is something like EAV data model).

In prepared query from my question on this line

```
K.value < :unit_top
```

PHP/MySQL is supposing that parameter :unit_top is the same datatype as K.value  column (`VARCHAR`) so it compares-collation them like strings ???, and the string "910" is later then "1000".

If you replace parameter ":unit_top" with variable $user_unit_top

```
K.value < $user_unit_top
```

or a literal

```
K.value < 1000
```

Then Php is doing numeric comparison, and "1000" is bigger then "910"

*If you change table `users_contacts` column named 'value' from `VARCHAR` to `INT` then the

```
K.value < :unit_top
```

comparison will be numeric

I think this is very inconsistent behavior, because if you do the following

```
$a = "1000";  
$b = " 910";  
var_dump($a < $b);
```

PHP will do automatic type casting and then numeric commparison, ...

Am I wrong ?

Comment: You are partially incorrect, as specified on the `execute()` documentation, [\[sic\]](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)  **All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR.** If you need to declare another data type for the parameter being sent to MySQL, you would use `$sth->bindParam(':unit_btm', $user_unit_btm, PDO::PARAM_INT);` With the column data type statement, [\[sic\]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) MySQL performs an automatic conversion to the column's data type for the comparison.

Comment: @fyrye thanx man, you have then claer it completly, you can put that as an answer so I can accept it. Do you maybe know how can that be done not with type of binding/command that you have done in your example "$sth->bindParam( ..." but with a the type "$upload_user-> execute( .." of binding that i  had done in my question?

Comment: Sadly PDO still  does not support parameter type specifications within `PDOStatement::execute`, similar to `mysqli::bind_param('ss', $a, $b)`. The only way to force a data type when using `execute` would be to implement casting of the parameters within your query. Such as `CAST('1000' AS SIGNED)` or `CAST(1000 AS CHAR)`